# JAWS Accessibility issue - Multiple reads for live region in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, accessibility, jaws-screen-reader

We have a modal dialog with multiple dependent dropdowns, selecting the value
in one dropdown repopulates the dependent drop down dynamically.

Because of this behaviour, JAWS is reading all the fields again whenever any of the drop down options are repopulated.

Example, Dummy markup

```
<div role="dialog">
   <div>
      <select id = "one">
        <option value="0">A</option>
        <option value="1">B</option>
        <option value="2">C</option>
      </select>
   </div>

   <div aria-live="polite">
      <select id = "two">
        <!-- dynamically populated options -->
        <option value="1">BC</option>
      </select>
   </div>

   <div aria-live="polite">
      <select id = "three">
        <!-- dynamically populated options -->
         <option value="1">BD</option>
      </select>
   </div>
</div>
```

Selecting the value in dropdown "one" populates the options in drop down "two" and similarly dropdown "three" is dependent on value of drop down "two".

Jaws reads all the fields properly in Chrome and firefox, however in Internet explorer 11, it starts reading the fields from the begining whenever any dropdown options are repopulated.

Additional details
Jaws version - 15
Using angular ui modal dialog
The browser reads from the begining  whenever there is any updated in the dom of the dialog.

**Update - here's the plnkr** - http://plnkr.co/edit/A2mcE2TfFavNEIlnFuPY?p=preview

Let me know if any further details are required, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you please show the markup of the dynamically populated options?

Comment: @Roman, updated the question with options markup

Comment: where is the live region?

Comment: @unobf updated the question, please have a look

Answer (score 0):

ARIA live regions are intended to read out updates to the visible (i.e. not display:none) content of the element it is placed on. Your HTML markup is working properly in IE11 with JAWS. There are a lot of differences in the implementations of ARIA live between browsers and assistive technologies that are causing the differences you are seeing.

The default behavior for aria-live="polite" is for the AT to read out all additions to the region. In the code above, this means it should read out all the options you have populated.

Angular.js will sometimes repopulate the entire DOM of a region when something inside the model or scope changes and some ATs will announce aria live regions when the nodes are inserted into the document.

It is not clear to me what your code is trying to achieve and what you mean by JAWS reads the fields properly in Chrome and Firefox. If you could describe your desired outcome, I could provide more guidance.

Comment: I would create a plnkr for this and post the same today

Comment: I do not see the markup you are mentioning in the plnker

Comment: Yeah markup differs slightly, but i am able to reproduce the issue, did you try reading it through jaws in IE 11 ?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently IE has some issues with [role="dialog"] attribute, if we remove this attribute from the modal dialog at the time of changing selected value of "first drop down", the issue gets resolved.

basically onChange of the first select, i am finding the element with role="dialog" and removing the attribute "role". This somehow fixes the problem
and JAWS reads the modal properly on repopulating the dependent drop downs